# Query Doesn't pick a column i m passing in laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my migrate

```
    public function up()
    {
     Schema::create('add_admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->date('expiry_date');
            $table->string('showAdminP');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('id');
        });
    }
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function addAdmin()
    {
        $firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName=$_POST['lastName'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];

        $hashed = Hash::make('password', ['rounds' => 12]);

        if($password==$cpassword)
        {
            $main=['firstName' => $firstName , 'lastName' => $lastName , 'email' => $email , 'mobile' => $mobile ,'password' => $hashed , 'adminShowP' => $password];
            // dd($main);
            \App\Models\AddAdmin::create($main);
            return view('admin.addAdmin');
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter Correct Password")</script>
            <?php
            return view('admin.addAdmin');
        }
    }
```

Here is my Model

```
    class AddAdmin extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'email',
        'mobile',        
        'expiry_date'
    ];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

It give an error as: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `add_admins` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `mobile`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (firstName, lastName, xyz@example.com, 2121212121, 2022-02-08 10:53:42, 2022-02-08 10:53:42))

Comment: `password` hasn't been set as fillable yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You.... I forget to add password column in fillable array in model